# Is there a WordPress plugin to design WebGL?

Tags: plugin-development, javascript

I have been working as a WordPress designer/developer for some time and now I've decided to write a plugin myself. I also have some OpenGL experience (not web based).

I was thinking is it worth investing my time learning WebGL and then using it to create a WebGL designer plugin for WordPress?

**To elaborate:**

My plugin would allow designers and non-coders to design WebGL based animations and games using basic building blocks and preset animations. It wouldn't be as good as writing the code yourself but it'd be a good start. It would be as simple as "drag and drop" and all the code will automatically be generated by this plugin.

Is it a good idea? Is there really a need for it? Is WordPress a suitable platform for this? And most importantly are there any existing plugins for designing WebGL out there?

Comment: Recommendation of plugins or themes or anything such is beyond the scope of this community. Please check [how to ask](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what not to ask](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Now please edit the question accordingly for seeking help from the community.

Comment: I wasn't asking for recommendation of a plugin. I was asking to make sure there isn't any existing plugin before I start writing one.

Comment: Also please read other parts of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it is possible to use WordPress for giving users the possibility of creating and embedding WebGLs.

The WebGL Script itself will have nothing to do with WordPress itself, although you can use data from WordPress to display in your animation.

To get you started, your Plugin would consist of two different parts:

- The creation of the animation (Backend)
- The presentation of the animation (Frontend)

#### Backend

I will not talk about the creation page for your animations, as this is not in the scope of this community and WordPress.

If you have this script, you can add [a new menu page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page) to present the interface for the user. Think about which data you need to store in the database. Maybe you could create [a Custom Post Type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types) and place the animation in a [Meta Box](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box), saving the Information as [Custom Fields](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) in the database.

This really depends on how your animation is structured - be sure to untilize the WordPress core functions for your database activities and content management.

#### Frontend

You also have different possibilities of displaying the animation in the frontend. For the javascript, use [`wp_enqueue_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) to ensure it is handled the right way.

The output of the content can, depending on how you intended and implemented your scripts, be handled by a custom-post-template, a [shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API), a [widget](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API) or a [filter for existing content](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference), and many other ways.

**Almost anything is possible to develop in WordPress.**

As far as i know there is no Plugin that provides thsi functionality so far.

Just be sure to implement it the right way, and everything should be fine. If you have any specific questions during development, please don't hesitate to ask!

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll contact you if I'm stuck with something.